# FFT of a matrix and its square.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fourier-analysis, image-processing

I am doing something computationally intensive that requires that I compute the fast fourier transform of a matrix, let's say $A$, and also compute the FFT of its square, $A^2$.

I am wondering if there is some property of the FFT of $A$ that relates to the FFT of $A^2$ that would be less computationally intensive than doing two FFTs.

Comment: The matrix $A$ wouldn't be circulant by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing about the structure of the input, you can always save yourself at last one FFT operation along the columns (or rows). Assume $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$, and let $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$ be the column transform and $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ be the row transform. Then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{A})&=&\mathbf{RAC} \\
\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{A}^2)&=&\mathbf{RAAC}
\end{array}
$$

If you store $\mathbf{RA}$ (or $\mathbf{AC}$), you can then reuse it when finding $\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{A}^2)$:

```
tmp   = fft(A,[],1);
Afft  = fft(tmp,[],2);
A2fft = tmp * fft(A,[],2);
```